# How to add to PATH variable with a WIX for everyone: admin and standard users?

Tags: windows, path, wix, environment-variables, environment

I'm trying to set a global PATH environment variable along with my custom variable using WIX installer. I do the following:

```
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="COMPANYFOLDER" Name="my company">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="app name">

          <!-- blah blah -->

        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>


    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">

      <!-- Add environment variables -->
      <Component Id="idPathEnvSys" Guid=".....">
        <Environment Id="idEnvPathSys" Name="PATH" Action="set" Part="last" System="yes" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" Permanent="no"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="idPathEnvUsr" Guid=".....">
        <Environment Id="idEnvPathUsr" Name="PATH" Action="set" Part="last" System="no" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" Permanent="no"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="EnvVarsSys" Guid=".....">
        <Environment Id="idEnvMyPathSys" Name="MYPATH" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" Part="all" System="yes" Action="set" Permanent="no" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="EnvVarsUsr" Guid="....">
        <Environment Id="idEnvMyPathUsr" Name="MYPATH" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" Part="all" System="no" Action="set" Permanent="no" />
      </Component>

    </DirectoryRef>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="!(loc.ProductName)" Level="1">

      <!-- main components first -->

      <ComponentRef Id='idPathEnvSys' />
      <ComponentRef Id='idPathEnvUsr' />
      <ComponentRef Id='EnvVarsSys' />
      <ComponentRef Id='EnvVarsUsr' />
    </Feature>
```

It compiles just fine but when I install it, for some reason it only adds the system variable. So in other words, if I run a command prompt as admin and do `set path` it shows my `PATH` addition. But when I do the same from a regular user account, it is not there.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your ALLUSERS property set to?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: Sorry, I don't know Wix that well to know what `ALLUSERS` does. Where am I supposed to add it? I have the following in the package tag: `<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine"`

Comment: Try posting the entire WiX example source - we could try to reproduce. There may be a reason why the component isn't being installed, check that with a verbose log. Look at the generated MSI file with Orca to see what the Environment table entries look like and check the MSI docs.